# rangeslider.js - not pulling correct value number in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangeslider

I'm using `rangeslider.js` to hide or show images based on whether the value sits within a bucket ( at this point; above or below 1500 ) and I'm getting a weird response.

My slider is set up like this:

```
<input id="sliderone" 
    type="range"
    min="0"       // default 0
    max="3000"    // default 100
    step="1"      // default 1
    value="300"   // default min + (max-min)/2
>
```

My javascript is like this

```
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
var result  = document.getElementById('js-result');
var values  = getValues(sliders);

$(sliders).rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
}).on('change', function() {
    var values = getValues(sliders);
    updateResult(result, values);
    console.log(values);
});

$(sliders).rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
}).on('change', function() {
    var values = getValues(sliders);
    updateResult(result, values);
    console.log(values);
});

updateResult(result, values);

function newchangepic1() {
    var newvalue = values[0];
    console.log(newvalue);

    if (newvalue < 1500) {
          $(".img-one").attr("src","images/travel.png");
    } else if ( newvalue > 1500) {
          $(".img-one").attr("src","images/plant-color.png");
    }
}

function newchangepic3() {
    var newvalue = values[1];
    console.log(newvalue);

    if (newvalue < 1500) {
        $(".img-two").attr("src","images/hdb.png");
    } else if ( newvalue > 1500) {
        $(".img-two").attr("src","images/plane.png");
    }
}
```

When I do

```
console.log(values);
```

It prints my array as expected, updating with each movement.

```
var newvalue = values[0];
console.log(newvalue);
```

But when I try to read one of the values inside of the array I get 300. the initial value I set in HTML.

[image: Array results - 300]
I can't get my head around why this is happening but I'm a bad at coding, so am probably missing something.

Any help?

Comment: try using parseInt(value)

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 where?

Comment: wherever you need to use a value you got from the slider. e.g. parseInt(values[0])

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 -  Didn't seem to do anything for me? Still getting the same result.

Comment: function getValues is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var values  = getValues(sliders);

$(sliders).rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
}).on('change', function() {
    values = getValues(sliders); //<---------
    updateResult(result, values);
    console.log(values);
});

$(sliders).rangeslider({
    polyfill: false
}).on('change', function() {
    values = getValues(sliders);//<---------
    updateResult(result, values);
    console.log(values);
});
```

You should probably not declare a local variable 'values' if you intend to use the global array to store the latest values.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, was using an example and trying to modify. Didn't think about this. :)

Comment: Yeah these kind of error happen, and if you pay close attention you are using the same code twice which basically do the same thing. Good to know you got it resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed the [rangeslider.js](http://rangeslider.js.org/). From it's `API` it looks like the correct way is to use the `onSlide` change handler and you should update any global, local variable with this method. See the [JsFiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/uhvufov4/3/) where I have updated the global variable `slideValue` based on slide change event.

The partial code from above jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sliders = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
    var result  = document.getElementById('js-result');

    var slideValue; // This global value gets updated with each slide event

    $(sliders).rangeslider({
        polyfill: false,

        // Handle the slide change event and update value accordingly
        onSlide: function(pos, value) {
            slideValue = value;
            console.log('Value updated to ', value);
        }
    });
});
```

Let us know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks, already fixed it with above but this helped me make another aspect much more efficient:)